# apache to nginx rewrite

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting

I am having some issued just changed from apache to nginx and I need to setup
some rewrite on apache I used this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php
```

However nginx will not recognize this rule as it is for apache.
Now I have tried to go to nginx manuel and Google without much luck.
What I want it to do is take the url.

[www.mydomain.com/index.php/mycontrollername](http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/mycontrollername)
[www.mydomain.com/index.php/mycontrollername/](http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/mycontrollername/)

I want it to work with and without trailing slash.

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule)?

Comment: I did yes, however as i says "WARNING: this article is obsoleted. Please refer to http://nginx.org/en/docs/ for the latest official documentation."
So I went there however nginx config is quite new to me.
however we've since changed our minds and want it to only show index.php no matter what "link" the clients press but I still come up empty handed.